# Extra vertical bar when rendering subscript using inline Latex in iPython Notebook

Tags: latex, mathjax, jupyter-notebook

So, I'm trying to get the hang of using inline Latex in iPython Notebook, and I get a funny rendering of even the simplest of code to just add a subscript:

code in my markdown cell: `The slope $J_1$`

renders like this:

[image: J with a subscript 1, but a vertical bar adjacent to the 1]

I notice that when I first open the notebook, as the page is loading, the subscript displays properly (no vertical bar) but only briefly, but when the page is fully loaded, the rendered result changes and shows the vertical bar. The font appears to change in that process as well.

I've also downloaded other people's notebooks that use inline Latex, which look fine when viewed with the Jupyter nbViewer online;
(for example, http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/rszeto/umich-eecs545-lectures/blob/master/lecture02_linear-algebra-optimization/Lecture%202%20-%20Linear%20Algebra%20and%20Optimization.ipynb renders fine, but if I download the notebook and look at it with my local Jupyter viewer, I see the same vertical bar thing happening for subscripts in the Latex bits of the notebook)

I'm running iPython ver 4.0.1, viewing the notebook using Chrome (Version 48.0.2564.109 m) running on Win 7.

Is there a fix to render things properly? I don't see the vertical bar problem when I open the notebook using Internet Explorer.

Comment: It's a bug/change in Chrome; we're introducing a workaround to fix it.